# Calculate 1 week before the last Sunday and from today to last Sunday

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdbc

I am storing some days and hours as timestamp in my MySQL table. What I want to do now is retrieve every day that a specific user worked from last Sunday until the Sunday before (One week of work). And the other option is retrieve every day from today until last Sunday (current week). Some employees does not work everyday.

I don't know how I can code this in Java or whether there is a specific MySQL function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Java, you can put the Calendar class to good use to find the previous Sunday :

`Calendar c = Calendar;`
`c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);`
`Date lastSunday = c.getTime();`

you can then decrement by 1 WEEK_OF_MONTH to find the Sunday before that :

`c.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, -1);`
`Date sundayBeforeThat = c.getTime();`

Comment: Thanks. So the first 3 lines of the code will retrieve the data of the last Sunday. For example today is 27-04-2012 (Friday). The date in this variable will be 22-04-2012?
Thanks again

Comment: Actually I've tried this code and it works a bit different. The first line should be Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance; The second line returns the next day not the before. But I appreciate the help. Now I can work around it and find a suitable solution to my problem.

Comment: oh yes I forgot the ".getInstance()", my bad :/  as for the returning of the next day, there could be an internal implementation subtility that goes to the next sunday or the previous one depending on current day of the week... so take this part of the code with a grain of salt

Comment: This Answer ignores the crucial issue of time zones. `Calendar` is implicitly using the JVM’s current default time zone. That means your results will vary; not good.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )
         .with( TemporalAdjusters.previous( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) )
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes.

Remember that the [TIMESTAMP data type in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) is in UTC time zone.

In contrast, you want particular dates for particular day-of-week value where a particular time zone is critical. A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

Let's get the last Sunday, excluding today if it were a Sunday. Use a `TemporalAdjuster` implementation found in the `TemporalAdjusters` (note plural) class. Specify a `DayOfWeek` enum object.

```
LocalDate previousSunday = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.previous( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ) ;
```

Get the Sunday further back.

```
LocalDate startingSunday = previousSunday.minusWeeks( 1 ) ;
```

We need exact moment, not entire date. Get the first moment of the day. Do not assume that means the time-of-day of 00:00:00. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) means that the day might begin at a time like 01:00:00. Let java.time figure that out.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = startingSunday.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Next we need the ending time. Actually, not the ending time. Determining the split second ending of the week is tricky. The common practice in date-time work is to use the Half-Open approach to defining a span of time. In Half-Open, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. That means we want to start at the first moment of one Sunday and run up to, but not include, the first moment of the following Sunday.

Note that you cannot use `BETWEEN` in SQL for Half-Open, as that command is Closed, meaning both beginning and ending are inclusive.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = previousSunday.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

The query in MySQL will be done in UTC. So let's extract `Instant` objects from the `ZonedDateTime` objects as they are always in UTC by definition.

```
Instant start = zdtStart.toInstant() ;
Instant stop = zdtStop.toInstant() ;
```

If your JDBC driver supports JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly use these `Instant` objects in your query via [`PreparedStatement::setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-) and `ResultSet::getObject`.

This SQL code is untested, but should point you in the right direction.

```
String sql = "SELECT * from tbl_ WHERE col_ >= ? AND col_ < ? ; " ;
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
pstmt.setObject( 1 , start ) ;
pstmt.setObject( 2 , stop ) ; 
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery() ;
…
    Instant instant = rs.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).