# How to check if a Date falls in a certain week or Quarter

Tags: java

I need a java logic to check if a certain date(lets assume 18-04-2017) falls in the current week or not.
Also We have 4 quarters in an year
(Jan, Feb, Mar) - 1Q
(Apr, May, june) - 2Q
So i need to know if this same date falls in the current Quarter or not.
Will appreciate any replies

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Should not have been closed as "too broad" as it is quite specific. But it should be closed as a duplicate of many Questions on quarters and many Questions on testing if a date lies within a range. Tip: `org.threeten.extra.YearQuarter::atDay` and `::atEndOfQuarter`.

Answer (score 3):

I would say do these steps,

1 - figure out first and last day of the week
[Get current week start and end date in Java - (MONDAY TO SUNDAY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890644/get-current-week-start-and-end-date-in-java-monday-to-sunday)

2 - check if the date falls in between that range or not
[Java: how do I check if a Date is within a certain range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494180/java-how-do-i-check-if-a-date-is-within-a-certain-range)
    - if yes, it falls in the week
    - if no, it doesn't

3 - do the same for the quarters, have start and end date, and check if the date falls in between them or not

```
   //import java.util.*;
   //import java.text.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        Date dateToTest = sdf.parse("18/04/2017");

        //lets assume the date source is a variable, hence extract year off of it

        String firstDateInString = "01/04/" +  Integer.toString(getYear(dateToTest));
        String secondDateInString = "01/07/" +  Integer.toString(getYear(dateToTest));
        String thirdDateInString = "01/10/" +  Integer.toString(getYear(dateToTest));

        Date firstDate = sdf.parse(firstDateInString);
        Date secondDate = sdf.parse(secondDateInString);
        Date thirdDate = sdf.parse(thirdDateInString);


        //check if in first quarter
        //if date is before April it has to be first Q
        if (dateToTest.before(firstDate)) {
            System.out.println("First Quarter");
            return;
        }
        //check if in second quarter
        //if date is before August it has to be first Q
        if (dateToTest.before(secondDate)) {
            System.out.println("Second Quarter");
            return;
        }

        //check if in 3rd quarter
        //if date is before August it has to be first Q
        if (dateToTest.before(thirdDate)) {
            System.out.println("third Quarter");
            return;
        }

        //well then the date must be in 4th quarter
        System.out.println("Fourth quarter");
    } catch (Exception err) {
        System.out.println(err);
    }
}

private static int getYear(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    return cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

}
```

DISCLAIMER: This code is not the optimal method. Please note that here I don't assume current date or year. Purpose here is to show general strategy only.

Comment: thanks..Implemented it for Week..Now need to figure out a way for the quarters...

Comment: hi @shahed please check updated answer for a sample. Please note that the sample doesn't answer your question directly. You will still need to do some work to check for current year's quarters. I hope it helps :)

Comment: I think this serves the purpose..thanks a lot Samip Sir..
I ll try will give u the feedback